# Why is base58("foobar") not equal to base58("foo") + base58("bar")?

Tags: javascript, buffer, base58

```js
import { encode } from "bs58"

const foobar = Buffer.from("foobar")

console.log(foobar, encode(foobar))
// <Buffer 66 6f 6f 62 61 72> t1Zv2yaZ

const foo = Buffer.from("foo")
const bar = Buffer.from("bar")

console.log(Buffer.concat([foo, bar]), `${encode(foo)}${encode(bar)}`)
// <Buffer 66 6f 6f 62 61 72> bQbpa3cM
```

I don’t understand why buffers are identical but output from base58 is different.

Comment: Padding maybe...

Comment: Thanks for helping out @Keith. My (perhaps naive) understanding is that Base58 does not use padding.

Comment: I mean numeric padding, base58 does not divide into 256 (byte).   If you encoded 2 sets of base58 that were dividable by 256 they would be the same.

Comment: why does this work? `console.log(encode(Buffer.concat([foo,bar])))` <- `t1Zv2yaZ`

Comment: @Keith Interesting… can you please expand on numeric padding? For my use case, two concatenated blocks of ciphertext need to be indistinguishable from single block (hence why I am contemplating Base58 over Base64 which has padding).

Comment: A better example, if you encoded 57 you would of course get `z`, but if you encoded 115 you get `2z`  115 = 58 + 57,  But what about 255, `5Q`, as you can see 5Q is not at a boundary and has more space (empty), but your now stopping.  Hope that makes sense..  And your encoding bytes (3 * 256), and this ends at `EE`, again lots of space left for encoding.  `EF, EG, EH.. etc`

Comment: @Keith Still wrapping my head around your example… so according to you, would two concatenated Base58 strings of ciphertext be indistinguishable from each other? My (perhaps naive) assumption is that numerical padding does not reveal much if underlying data is ciphertext.

Comment: And the last example, lets say you are encoding `[58,58]`,  58 = `21`,  but 58,58 = (58 * 256) + 58 = 14906 = `5S1`   So  `2121` is then of course not equal to `5S1`..

Comment: `if underlying data is ciphertext.`  ciphertext is irrelevant here, base58 is just for encoding very large numbers.  Like my last example `[58,58]` in a buffer is not 2 58's.  It's 14906.

Comment: So.  `66 6f 6f` is `6713199`  and that in b58 = `bQbp`, and `66 6f 6f 62 61 72` = 112628796121458, in b58 = `t1Zv2yaZ`..  Do you understand how I got those No's?.

Comment: @Keith Just had breakfast, making a coffee and about to jump down the rabbit hole. Will reach out if I still don’t get it. Thanks again for helping out.